# how to use spinner mode for timepicker in .net maui

Tags: .net, maui

I want to use spinner mode for timepicker control in .net maui
but when use this control show clock mode in my app
please help me to change mode of timepicker
[Currently displaying this model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQiW.png)

[Customize Android TimePicker to use Spinner in .net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255027/customize-android-timepicker-to-use-spinner-in-net-maui)
i use this solution
but it is not work
and i think it is not correctly solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this case about the [TimePickerDialog in spinner mode in the native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775481/timepickerdialog-in-spinner-mode), you can pass the deprecated `Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar` theme to the TimePickerDialog's constructor.

And you can use the custom handler to do that. At first, please create the Custom Handler class in the **/Platforms/Android**:

```
public class MyTimePickerHandler : TimePickerHandler
    {
        protected override TimePickerDialog CreateTimePickerDialog(int hour, int minute)
        {
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog =  new(
                              this.Context,
                         global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialogNoActionBar,
                         (s, e) => {
                                    this.VirtualView.Time = new TimeOnly(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute,0).ToTimeSpan();
                                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(this.VirtualView.Time);
                                    this.PlatformView.Text = dateTime.ToString("h:mm tt"); ;
                              },
                              this.VirtualView.Time.Hours,
                              this.VirtualView.Time.Minutes,
                              false);
           
            return timePickerDialog;
        }
    }
```

And then use the custom handler in the mauiprogram.cs:

```
builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  })
                  .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                  {
#if ANDROID
                        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(TimePicker), typeof(Platforms.Android.MyTimePickerHandler));
#endif
                  }) ;
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using the TimePicker from a <input> tag. Please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448105/blazor-hybrid-maui-native-android-timepicker thanks a lot!

Comment: Any thoughts on this @liyun-zhang-msft ?

Comment: The input is the control in the html and renderered by the webview. And sorry I have no idea about this. @Smith5727