# Blazor Hybrid MAUI Native Android Timepicker

Tags: c#, android, mobile, blazor, material-design

We are using a TimePicker in MAUI like this

```
 <input type="time" id="arrivalTimePickerH" name="arrivalTimePickerHT" style="width:100%;height:40px;border-bottom:1px #bdbdbd solid;" onfocus="this.showPicker()">
```

Now we got a lot of complaints from users that they don't like this Material Design Native TimePicker with this round-style clock. Which looks like this:

[image]

I have implemented the code from this Stack Overflow post [how to use spinner mode for timepicker in .net maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76287106/how-to-use-spinner-mode-for-timepicker-in-net-maui)

But it does not work, the code compiles but the clock is still the round type clock. How can I get the spinner clock in Blazor Hybrid MAUI?